# Broadcast message and Get response using Javascript (upnp M-SEARCH)

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js, sockets, google-chrome-extension

I want to send and MSearch request to my DLNA server and Get the response using Javascript. I have implemented the code in C# but I need it in javascript since I am writing a Chrome Add-on(Html,JS,CSS).
The problem is I dont know Js well and I have read Node.js documentation but cannot understand it.

This is my C# code

```
    public void search()
    {                                                                 
        IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6000);  to 1900 to 
        IPEndPoint MulticastEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250"), 1900);

        Socket UdpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp); 
        UdpSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        UdpSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, true);
        UdpSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 2);
        UdpSocket.Bind(LocalEndPoint);
        UdpSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250"), LocalEndPoint.Address));


        Console.WriteLine("UDP-Socket setup done...\r\n");

        string SearchString = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1 \r\nMX:3\r\n\r\n"; //Wifi router connectify: => ST:urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1
        UdpSocket.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SearchString), SocketFlags.None, MulticastEndPoint);  // ==> HTTPMU broadcast
        UdpSocket.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SearchString), SocketFlags.None, MulticastEndPoint);
        UdpSocket.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SearchString), SocketFlags.None, MulticastEndPoint); 

        Console.WriteLine("M-Search sent...\r\n");

        byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[64000];

        int ReceivedBytes = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (UdpSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                ReceivedBytes = UdpSocket.Receive(ReceiveBuffer, SocketFlags.None);                     

                if (ReceivedBytes > 0)
                {
                    string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReceiveBuffer, 0, ReceivedBytes);
                    if (!responseString.Contains("Windows/6.8 UPnP/1.1 Guru")) continue;

                    string url = GetResourceUriFromHTTPResp(responseString);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(url);
                        UdpSocket.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My main Target is to obtain the url of the server, when user clicks add-on, to navigate to the url.

If my only options are to use external javascript libraries like Node.js, please explain to me in simple language how to have refrence to the library to enable me to use its functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use [chrome.socket](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) API from chrome extension.
   Therefore, it's not possible to communicate with DLNA server from
   extension's code.
2. You can do the work with node.js, but you can't
   reference node.js from chrome extension, because it's not "external
   javascript library", but standalone javascript platform.
3. The way to get the things done is to use some proxy between chrome extension and DLNA server, that will listen to http requests from your extension, and pass the data to DLNA server and from server back to extension. Of course, this proxy can we written in node.js, but you can use ASP.NET platform for this purposes as well, especially if you know C#.